# Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Experiencing Memory Pressure On 2/3 nodes

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have an azure Synapse instance. It's performing much slower than I expect, with queries largely stuck on data movement or shuffle steps.

When I check the DMVs for memory pressure. I see 2 nodes are **maxed out at 100% memory usage**, but the third is sat at sort of 12%.

I also verified that normally fast queries are slow whilst this memory pressure is high.

I presume that nodes can't borrow memory from each other, but then I'm also confused why 2 could have such high usage when the third is so low. I'm wondering if we need to do some kind of table rebuilding to get the queries more balanced.

The instance is a 3 node 1000DWU instance.

EDIT:
Note that even in periods of low query activity, the memory doesn't seem to be decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as My experience the **Data Distribution,Partitioning and Query Optimization**
Can improve & provide some insights into optimizing memory usage

So for example Speaking of Data Distribution
I have created a table and distribute the data.
This is my table with below schema

```
CREATE  TABLE table01 (
ID INT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
Age INT,
Email VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Create a temporary table with the desired partition ranges

```
CREATE  TABLE table01_new
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = HASH (ID),
PARTITION (ID RANGE  RIGHT  FOR  VALUES (1, 5, 10)) -- Specify the partition ranges
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM table01_Temp
OPTION (LABEL = 'CTAS: table01_new');
DROP  TABLE table01_Temp;
EXEC sp_rename 'table01_new', 'table01';
```

[image]

This below way you can do the data distribution.   and few of the ways you can do the data distrubution are

- Round-robin distribution
- Hash distribution
- Replicated distribution
- Columnstore distribution

As an example I am using the Round Robin for the below table.

```
CREATE  TABLE table01_Temp_New
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM table01_Temp;
```

[image]

And the Other way you can sort memory usage issue is to using the query optimisation like consider using the INDEXING,
Aviod Using the WildCards Like Operators,
Also choosing the Using appropriate Data types is also One of the Key for memory usage.

The above steps should help you resolve the  Memory Pressure on nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm confused as to how this can help? 

1. I have several thousand tables, each is designed in line with synapse guidance (mostly).
2. Your comment advises me to build tables using distributions. But how does this help. Each distribution moves data across all nodes (unless e.g. you hash on a low cardinality column, whcih we don't do)
3. Relating to memory usage - again those points imply high overall memory usage, but this question is about imbalanced memroy usage.

Comment: I understand table distribution and query optimization are interrelated. Optimizing your queries to leverage the distribution strategy of your tables can help improve load balancing and reduce memory pressure.